# What is the reliable way to select current directory's python with pyenv + pipenv or pip

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, pipenv, pyenv

I have two problems:

pipenv ignores pyenv settings;

my pip shortcuts are ignoring pyenv settings too:

```bash
iuri@tartaruga:~$ pyenv version
3.9.16 (set by /home/iuri/.pyenv/version)
iuri@tartaruga:~$ pyenv local 3.10
iuri@tartaruga:~$ pyenv version
3.10.9 (set by /.python-version)
iuri@tartaruga:~$ pyenv exec python -m pip --version
pip 22.3.1 from /home/iuri/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)
iuri@tartaruga:~$ pip --version
pip 22.3.1 from /home/iuri/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
iuri@tartaruga:~$ pyenv versions
  system
  3.9.14
  3.9.16
* 3.10.9 (set by /.python-version)
  3.11.1
iuri@tartaruga:~$ pyenv exec python -m pipenv install torch
Creating a virtualenv for this project...
Pipfile: Pipfile
Using /home/iuri/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/bin/python3 (3.11.1) to create virtualenv...
^C
iuri@tartaruga:~$ python --version
Python 3.10.9
iuri@tartaruga:~$ pyenv exec python --version
Python 3.10.9
iuri@tartaruga:~$ pyenv exec python -m pip --version
pip 22.3.1 from /home/iuri/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)
iuri@tartaruga:~$ python -m pip --version
pip 22.3.1 from /home/iuri/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)
iuri@tartaruga:~$ pip --version
pip 22.3.1 from /home/iuri/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
iuri@tartaruga:~$ pip3
pip3     pip3.10  pip3.11  pip3.9
iuri@tartaruga:~$ pip3.10 --version
pip 22.3.1 from /home/iuri/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
iuri@tartaruga:~$ pyenv global
3.9.16
```

I know that pipenv can be forced into a python version easily, but why my linked pip binaries are not respecting pyenv?

Comment: `pip`s are not binaries, they are scripts, and the scripts can be run under different Pythons due to [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)). Investigate: `head -1 $(which pip)`

Comment: I always execute pip via my current python via commands like: `python -m pip install requests`. This tends to ensure pip is tied to the expected python for me.

Comment: @phd I am aware, that was just a way to clarify what I was trying to refer when saying 'pip'. Of course the shebang will be pointing to the wrong version, that is the issue I'm describing. Why pyenv shims 'magic' is not giving my shell the proper pip, even with `pyenv exec`